# Sum of Digits in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CubesSum {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        int input;

        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = in.nextInt();

        int number = input; //number is a temp variable
        int sum = 0;

        while(number>0){
            int t= number%10;
            sum += t*t*t;
            number = number/10;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the cubes of the digits is:" +sum);
    }
}
```

Okay so I'm using a while loop. For part B which is to modify to determine what integers of two, three, and four digits are equal to the sum of the cubes of their digits. So for example, 371 = 3³+7³+1³. Can someone tell me how to do it? I need to wrap a for loop around my while loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the part of your code that computes the sum of the cubes of the digits of a number, and make that a function:

```
int sumOfCubedDigits(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    // compute sum from number
    return sum;
}
```

Then, loop through all the 2-to-4 digit numbers and check whether they equal the sum of the cubes of their digits:

```
for (int n = 10; n < 10000; n++) {
    if (n == sumOfCubedDigits(n)) {
        // do whatever with n
    }
}
```

You could keep the sum-of-cubed-digits computation inside the `for` loop if you want, but it'd be a bit less readable.

---

Okay, so it looks like you haven't learned about function definitions yet. I shouldn't have assumed. Let's do it with a nested loop, then.

As you said, you need to wrap a `for` loop around your `while`. We need to consider all 2-to-4 digit numbers, so our loop will start at the first 2-digit number and end when it reaches the first 5-digit number:

```
for (int n = 10; n < 10000; n++) {
    // More code will go here.
}
```

Inside the loop, we need to compute the sum of the cubed digits of `n`. The code you wrote earlier to compute that modifies the number it's operating on, but we can't modify `n`, or we'll screw up the `for` loop. We make a copy:

```
for (int n = 10; n < 10000; n++) {
    int temp = n;
    int sum = 0;
    // Compute the sum of the digits of temp, much like you did before.
}
```

Finally, if the sum is equal to `n`, we do something to indicate it. Let's say your assignment said to print all such numbers:

```
for (int n = 10; n < 10000; n++) {
    int temp = n;
    int sum = 0;
    // Compute the sum of the digits of temp, much like you did before.
    if (sum == n) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to Java so it is kinda hard to understand. Could you please explain easier? I appreciate for your help!

Comment: @user3268146: Is there a specific aspect of the problem that you don't understand? It's difficult to explain at a more basic level without holding a conversation with you and working through the problem together, and StackOverflow is specifically not designed for that.

Comment: How can I take the part of the code that computes the sum of the cubes of the digits of a number, and make that a function:int sumOfCubedDigits(int number) {
    ...
}

Comment: @user3268146: I've fleshed out the skeleton of the function a bit more. Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: Sorry, not really..it would be awesome to know more about it..thanks

Comment: @user3268146: Can't help you much more, then. It's too hard to tell exactly what aspect you don't understand, and there's too much material I might have to explain. I don't know whether I should be explaining how functions work, or what gets executed in what order in a `for` loop, or the basics of how nested loops interact with each other. Your best bet is probably to read a textbook or talk to someone in person.

Comment: What does it mean to // compute sum from number and // do whatever with n

Comment: `compute sum from number` means compute the sum of the digits of `number`, just like you did in the code you wrote before. `do whatever with n` means do whatever it is you're supposed to do if the number is equal to the sum of the cubes of its digits. That probably involves printing something.

Comment: I did everything what you told me to.. This is my result http://i.imgur.com/0KMTspJ.png what did i do wrong?

Comment: @user3268146: Oh, geeze. If you haven't learned how to define functions yet, that was a solid try. If you *have* learned how to define functions, you really need to review how to do that. I'm guessing you haven't learned to define functions yet. Let's try it without the function.

Comment: @user3268146: I've expanded the answer with help for completing the program without defining a `sumOfCubedDigits` function.

Comment: Thanks so like this? http://i.imgur.com/3KnIIOu.png                However my output is: Enter a positive integer:
123
whatuwant10
The sum of the cubes of the digits is:27
whatuwant10
The sum of the cubes of the digits is:35
whatuwant10
The sum of the cubes of the digits is:36

Comment: @user3268146: That's about all the help I can give. You should be able to debug your program and finish it from here through your own effort; if you can't, you really need to read up on control flow and solidify your understanding of what happens when your program executes.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary integer `i`, it's `nth` digit `dn` is, (being n=1 the rightmost digit)

```
dn = (i % (10^n)) / (10^(n-1)) // all integer operations
```

as you can see, you'll need to know beforehand the number of digits of your `i`, otherwise, yes, you'll need a loop

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter number : ");
    int num =  input.nextInt();

    int temp = num, remainder;
    int sum = 0;

    while(temp %10 != 0){
        remainder = temp %10;
        sum = sum+ remainder ;
        temp = temp/10; 
    }            

    System.out.println("Sum of digit : " + sum);
```

=====OUTPUT====
Please enter number : 123
Sum of digit : 6

Comment: Limitation: don't use zero(0)!